# X11 Forwarding request failed

Tags: ssh, x11, forwarding

I'm trying to use `ssh -Y/X ManjaroHost` from my Mac, but get "X11 Forwarding request failed". I've searched for the solution for two weeks, and have tried many methods suggested by similar posts. It would be a great help to point out my mistakes!

Here are some experiments I've done. To make everything clear, I always  ssh from HostA to HostB.  HostA is the X server and ssh client, while HostB is the ssh server.

Experiment 1

HostA:  My Macbook.
HostB:  Another Linux cluster.
It works, perfectly,  GUI windows will popup on my Mac.
In HostA,  echo $DISPLAY --> /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.6AxM1TJrRh/org.xquartz:0
In HostB,  echo $DISPLAY --> localhost:10.0
So I think my Mac end works good.

Experiment 2

HostA:  My Macbook. HostB:  Manjaro Linux Lenovo.
HostA:  DISPLAY is /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.6AxM1TJrRh/org.xquartz:0
HostB:  DISPLAY is empty.
Here is the debug information from ssh -Yvvv

```
...
...
...
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 2: setting env LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = "3.4.15"
debug1: channel 2: setting env LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 2: setting env LC_TERMINAL = "iTerm2"
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
Last login: Wed Nov  9 13:55:34 2022 from 192.168.0.194
X11 forwarding request failed
```

Experiment 3

In case this is because of some internet setup,  I tried to ssh -Y 127.0.0.1 in Manjaro Linux Lenovo

HostA = HostB = Manjaro Linux Lenovo

HostA:  DISPLAY = :0

HostB (after ssh): DISPLAY is empty.

The debug information from ssh -Yvvv is

```
 ssh -Yvvv  127.0.0.1                                                           
...
...
...
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/bin/xauth  list :0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 100
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
**X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0**
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Wed Nov  9 14:43:39 2022 from 127.0.0.1
```

It still shows "X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0"

Here is my Manjaro sshd_config file

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost no
AllowTcpForwarding yes
AllowAgentForwarding yes
PermitRootLogin yes
```

ssh_config file

```
HOST *
    #ServerAliveInterval 60
    #ServerAliveCountMax 5
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    #ControlPersist yes
    ControlMaster auto
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

My Mac ssh_config file

```
HOST *
    ServerAliveInterval 60
    ServerAliveCountMax 5
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    ControlPersist yes
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
    identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_gmail
```

I think I've tried everything I can, but fail to figure out the issue. Appreciated if someone could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common cause is that the `xauth` package and thus executable are missing on the server. Run `which xauth` to find out. Usually you can install with `apt install xauth` or such.

If it is installed and X11 forwarding still fails: you can enable sshd debugging on the server side too.

Assuming you have root access on the server, find the script starting sshd. On a modern system using systemd, you can do `sudo systemctl status ssh` to find it. Mine is called `/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service`. Look for a line starting with `ExecStart=`. The debugging option for sshd is `-d`.

You can check the server logfile with `journalctl -b -a -u ssh`.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion of debugging! It helps!

Comment: Thanks @Jdehan for your great help! Now it works!

With sudo, I setup the debug mode for sshd in the remote server. From the debug information, I found that the sshd service is only loading /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, without loading .ssh/sshd_config file! So all my edit on ~/.ssh/sshd_config had never been really loaded into the system.

In ~/.ssh folder, only the keys and know_host file, and config works. But the ssh_config, sshd_config in .ssh does not, only if you explicitly using -f to load the files

Answer (score 3):

I my case the cause for the ssh client message "X11 forwarding request failed" was that the ssh daemon (on the server) was not able to bind to any port 6000+ (the X11 forwarding port range), because it tried only IPv6, and that wasn't working (it was in a docker container and probably switched-off).

The solution was to change a line in `/etc/sshd_config`: from `AddressFamily any` (the default) to `AddressFamily inet` (i.e., **no** inet6).

Comment: Thanks man - recently disabled ipv6 for security reasons and this was my case

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jdehan for his great help! Now it works!

With sudo, I setup the debug mode for sshd in the remote server. From the debug information, I found that the sshd service is only loading /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, without loading .ssh/sshd_config file! So all my edit on ~/.ssh/sshd_config had never been really loaded into the system.

In ~/.ssh folder, only the keys and know_host file, and config  works. But the ssh_config, sshd_config in .ssh does not, only if you explicitly using -f to load the files.

Comment: Glad it helped.

The /etc/ssh/sshd_config is meant just for the server process sshd. Your ~/.ssh/config is used by the outgoing ssh client process. There is no overlap in usage either way, unless you force them, which is definitely not recommended.